# I am running a webdriver test to login and finally click an element but getting error. The browser loads for sometimes and st

Tags: java, selenium

I have tried almost all element locators but the error still comes:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:    Unable to locate element://div[@class='ui.basic.blue.button']
```

Part of this java code:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys(temp1);
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(temp2);
driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm")).submit();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui.basic.blue.button']")).click();
```

Comment: Can you give us the URL or HTML content?

Comment: XXXXXX
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="sixteen wide mobile four wide computer column ui right aligned">
           
            <a href = "XXXXXXXXXX" >
                <div class="ui labeled button" tabindex="0">
              <div class="ui basic blue button" style="font-size:.7em;">
                <i class="icon reply"></i> XXXXXXXXXX
              </div>
              <a class="ui basic left pointing blue label" style="font-size:.7em;">
                1
              </a>
            </div>
            </a>
           
            </div>

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath expression is incorrect. There are 2 options

1. Use CssSelector: `By.cssSelector("div.ui.basic.blue.button")`
2. Change XPath expression to `By.xpath("//div[@class='ui basic blue button']")`

Comment: xpath is same as you are suggesting. And I have already tried option 1 also.

Comment: Your xpath is not the same, this one is correct, please note that there is a big difference, you need to use the exact value from class attribute, you are using a css selector as class value.

Comment: @AnjaniKumar Could you tell me if my answer solve your problem or not?

Comment: @Buaban  No. the problem still persisted.